# How to Display result with Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, console, output, console-application

I write a class in C# and I want to display in console.
But i can't display it.

My program doesn't have any errors, which means the program runs it but i can't see a result :(

Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: please include the code in your question.

Comment: ..please show some code.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Hello");`

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Console.WriteLine(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) to print the output, and [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) to wait for user input.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.Read();
```

Without Console.Read, sometimes output just comes, and program exits in a flash. So Output cannot be seen/verified easily.

Answer (score 2):

No Problem, I get what you are asking...

In regards to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

1. Write `Console.WriteLine("Where are you console?");` somewhere in your code - make sure you will definitely see it..
2. Press Debug button (or the play button)
3. In the Microsoft Visual Studio, Go to Debug -> Windows -> Output

A small 'Output' Windows should pop up and you can see your console write statements! - Obviously you gotta run the code and it will appear.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to see your output. This will wait the console screen until you press any key.

Comment: that would imply a certain IDE I guess?

Answer (score 0):

[On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you can find basic guide how to create console applications and how to output results.

Answer (score 0):

Your main structure must be in "Windows Form" architecture. So, try to attach parent (base) process, such as:

```
namespace MyWinFormsApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Environment.UserInteractive) // on Console..
            {
                // redirect console output to parent process;
                // must be before any calls to Console.WriteLine()
                AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

                // to demonstrate where the console output is going
                int argCount = args == null ? 0 : args.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("nYou specified {0} arguments:", argCount);
                for (int i = 0; i < argCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", args[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // launch the WinForms application like normal
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(or write a console app from scratch)